# kind of sport vs sport

Tags: phrase-usage

Are both sentences correct? Is the first one non common?

> My favourite kind of sport is tennis.

vs

> My favourite sport is tennis.

Answer (score 2):

Tennis is a sport, not a *kind* of sport. It would make more sense to say "My favourite kind of sport is athletics" (because that includes a number of different activities), or "My favourite kind of sport is ball games".

Comment: Interesting. In my native language we don't have this logic.

Comment: Can't you say "Apples and oranges are different kinds (or sorts) of fruit"?

Comment: On reflection, I suppose we can say "Apples are my favourite kind of fruit", as well as "my favourite fruit". It just seemed to me that a 'kind of sport' implied a group of sports with something in common.

Comment: "She is my kind of girl." "Tennis is my kind of sport."

Comment: So, are you sure that "kind of sport" means a number of different activities?

Comment: No, it doesn't _have_ to. It just seemed odd to me to refer to tennis as a 'kind of sport' when it is a specific game. Someone must agree with me, as I got one upvote!

Comment: It was done by me. Thanks.